# Repetition of column values in next row, using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am unable to solve this loop structure problem in SQL. I have two DATETIME parameters: `@Departure` and `@Arrival`. I am adding `NumberofHaltHrs` I need to get looping of @Departure and @Arrival as below.

Let's say I have

```
@Departure= 13/01/01 00:00:00(YY/MM/DD) and 
@Arrival=  13/01/10 02:00:00(YY/MM/DD)
NumofHaltHrs are like 2, 22, 26, 56 (this is a column of other table where I need to ass to result table)
```

Desired output:

```
      @Departure                     @Arrival
    13/01/01 00:00:00          13/01/01 02:00:00  //Adding NumOfHaltHrs (2Hrs )
    13/01/01 02:00:00          13/01/02 00:00:00  //NumOfHaltHrs (22 Hrs)
    13/01/02 00:00:00          13/01/03 02:00:00
    13/01/03 02:00:00          13/01/05 08:00:00
    13/01/05 08:00:00          ...
    ...
```

I need to insert @Departure,@Arrival,NumOfHaltHrs into Result Table where its structure is

```
JourneyDetailsTable: (JourneyID,HaltID,Departure,Arrival,NumOfHaltHrs)
Halt : HaltID,NumOfHaltDays
```

I tried looping but I could not get Arrival dates in Departure column.

Comment: please add your table structure and the query that you already have

Comment: As in first row `Time Taken = 2 hrs`, then in 2nd row why it is taking `22Hrs`?

Comment: @RJ1990 Here for each row time will be added according to NumOfHatHrs, where 1sr row value is 2 and second row value is 22Hrs

Comment: @LuisLL My output table will have Departure,Arrival,NumOfHaltHrs Columns , i need to insert these from UI taking NumOfHatHrs from Other dependent table Halt

Comment: @þÍńķ I don't understand what you are asking. do you need to `INSERT` or to `SELECT`. Please post the **SQL** that you already have and the tables structure

Comment: @LuisLL i have updated its structure..,

Comment: Please show your `solve this loop structure problem`, I mean what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb036/1)**

**Below is the Query :**

```
create table Halts (id int,NoOfHalts int)    
Go
insert into halts values(1,2),(2,22),(3,2),(4,22)
Go
select DATEADD(hour,
               T.sum - T.NoofHalts,
               Convert(datetime,'23/07/2012 00:00:00',103)) as Deaprture,
       DATEADD(hour,
               T.sum,
               Convert(datetime,'23/07/2012 00:00:00',103)) as Arrival ,NoofHalts
  from (select top (select COUNT(*) from Halts) 
               t1.id, 
               t1.NoOfHalts, 
               SUM(t2.NoOfHalts) as sum
          from Halts t1
         inner join Halts t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
         group by t1.id, t1.NoOfHalts
         order by t1.id
       ) T
```

Add number of Halts entry in `Halts` table which you wants in Output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Departure DATETIME

SET 
    @Departure = '01/13/01 00:00:00'

CREATE TABLE #NumofHaltHrs(HaltTime INT, ID INT IDENTITY(1,1))

INSERT INTO #NumofHaltHrs
    (HaltTime)
VALUES
    (2)
INSERT INTO #NumofHaltHrs
    (HaltTime)
VALUES
    (22)
INSERT INTO #NumofHaltHrs
    (HaltTime)
VALUES
    (26)
INSERT INTO #NumofHaltHrs
    (HaltTime)
VALUES
    (56)

DECLARE @UpdatedArrivalTime DATETIME, @NumberOfHaltRows INT, @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex INT
SET @UpdatedArrivalTime = @Departure
SET @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex = 1

SELECT
    @NumberOfHaltRows = COUNT(ID)
FROM #NumofHaltHrs

CREATE TABLE #Schedule(DEPARTURE DATETIME, ARRIVAL DATETIME)

WHILE @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex <= @NumberOfHaltRows
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HaltTime INT
    SELECT
        @HaltTime = HaltTime
    FROM #NumofHaltHrs
    WHERE ID = @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex

    INSERT INTO #Schedule
    VALUES
        (@UpdatedArrivalTime, DATEADD(hour, @HaltTime, @UpdatedArrivalTime))

    SET @UpdatedArrivalTime = DATEADD(hour, @HaltTime, @UpdatedArrivalTime)

    SET @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex = @NumberOfHaltRowsIndex + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Schedule
```

I don't know in which scenario you want to use it, so kindly check for performance if the data is huge.

Comment: Thanks.., Let me check

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @Departure, @Arrival, DATEDIFF(hh, @Departure, @Arrival) AS NumofHaltHrs 
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE YOR_WHERE_CONDITION
```

I am not sure if you want to have a result in this format. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, using a common table expression (and assuming NumHaltHrs is coming from a table with some kind of id or time to order by)

```sql
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT @Departure dtime, 0 NumOfHaltHrs, 0 rn
  UNION 
  SELECT DATEADD(hour, (SELECT SUM(NumOfHaltHrs) 
                        FROM bop a 
                        WHERE a.idHalt<=bop.idHalt), @departure),
         NumOfHaltHrs,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY idHalt)
  FROM bop
)
SELECT a.rn+1 HaltId, a.dtime Departure, 
       COALESCE(b.dtime, @Arrival) Arrival,
       COALESCE(b.numofhalthrs, 0) NumOfHaltHrs
FROM cte a LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.rn = b.rn-1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbb18/2).